# getParameter returns null in the servlet

Tags: servlets

i am trying to pass a string from my jsp to the servlet via href. I use this

```
<a href="MyServlet?select=title1"> Title1 </a>
```

then in the servlet i am trying to get the value of the select with this

```
String s = request.getParameter("select");
```

But it returns `null`. Why is that? Thank you!
**EDIT** I post the code of the servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userOption = request.getAttribute("select");
        System.out.println("Select is:" + userOption);
        //in the console i get: Select is:null
```

Comment: Your servlet was executed?

Comment: Is your servlet invoked properly? please show url pattern and your servlet method

Comment: are you sure you have put this code in your doGet method? because any link causes doGet method to invoke

Comment: yes the servlet is executed normally.

I am trying to get the value inside the:
`protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {`

Comment: please post your full code

Comment: ok i posted it in the question @PrasadKharkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should not be `String userOption = request.getAttribute("select");`

Please understand that **attributes are not parameters**

It should be `String userOption = request.getParameter("select");`

Comment: ok that was very silly of me.. i put getAttribute() but i thought i had put getParameter().. thx anyway!

Comment: Not to worry... happened with me also :)